# SessionListener (EventListener) to automatically Logout (Symfony)

Tags: php, security, symfony, session, session-timeout

I was trying to implement a SessionListener that should kick out a user in the background after x minutes of inactivity.
This is working well, but the listener is also called when the user is not even logged in - should not be that way.

So I tried to inject the TokenStorage into my listener but when I try to check if the user within this token does exist, I get the error message:

"The security context contains no authentication token. One possible
reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL."

As I read now in the internet, this is because the Listener is executed before the TokenStorage gets initialized within the "Symfony process".

How can I now only process the following code within the if statement when the user is logged in?

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{

    if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST) {
        return;
    }

    $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->start();
    $metadataBag = $session->getMetadataBag();

    $lastUsed = $metadataBag->getLastUsed();
    if ($lastUsed === null) {
        // the session was created just now
        return;
    }

    // timediff ...
    $timeDiff = ...

    // How to check here in addition that the user is logged in ?
    if($timeDiff > self::MINUTES)
    {
        $session->invalidate();
        $kicked_msg = $this->translator->trans('account.user.sessionTimeout', array(), 'User');
        $session->getFlashBag()->set('info_message', $kicked_msg);
    }

}
```

Security.yml firewall configuration:

```
 firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

My Service definition of the listener:

```
 library.verify_session.listener:
    class: Library\UserBundle\EventListener\SessionListener
    arguments: [@translator, @session, @security.token_storage, @security.authorization_checker]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 100, method: onKernelRequest }
    scope: request
```

For me, it seems as if the priority was the problem.
Http Firewall Listener has Priority of 8.

If I change my listener to priority 7, the error is gone because my Listener is executed after the Firewall Listener, and so the token exists.

Problem for me now:
I don't get logged out anymore by the session listener, i see the flashbag but it doesn't kick me out / cleans the session...? Why is that so?

**Solution:**

I tried everything I could imagine and the only full working way I found was the following:
1) When having logged in / authenticated, set a Session like "logged" => true
2) Check in the Listener for that Session variable in addition
3) Set the Listener Service to a priority > 8

---

All other ways would end up in a never ending "circuit" where one problem follows the other and in the end, you end up at the start point ..

Regards.

Comment: can you post your firewall configuration in `security.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to check your Token before you get the user, `if (null !== $this->security->getToken() && $this->security->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))` , depending on your symfony version of course.

As stated in this issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2753

Your listener is also used in other url where your firewall is not configured to, which is normal but on some cases in those url if the token doesn't exist it means the user is probably not connected. So the previous check should do it.

Comment: hey, this snippet won't work because the token will always return null, so the user will never be kicked out of his session. I updated my question with my firewall configuration.